# WebLogic Response with 503 HTTP Code

Tags: servlets, weblogic, servlet-filters, weblogic11g

I have a WS Server based on a cluster WebLogic (11 version). And try to answer with a 503 http code.

```
        response.setStatus(503);
```

Request is handled by custom HttpFilter

When i execute my service from browser on admin node of the server. I recieve an error message:

> No backend servers available

And i see in logs that my filter was executed 4-5 times

When i execute my service on specific node of the cluster i receive a bode of the response (which i specified in the code) and my service was launched only one times

What behaviour is the right? And how i can control number of service starts? (from admin node)

Comment: Do you only want one instance of your service running? Have you looked into Singleton Services? There is not enough information if your question for anyone to provide an answer. How are you accessing your service when it is executed multiple times? Have you put logging into your service so you know what server is executing it?

Comment: Initially i expect one HTTP Get call - one service execution. What's the benefit of Singleton Service in such case? I expect that my Get operation would be recieved on Admin Node and transfered (by internal Proxy) to some of node. When my service ran i put info about staring into database